# Arduino missing data Serial.println()

Tags: c++, tcp, arduino, esp8266, arduino-c++

I'm using an ESP8266 connected to an Arduino Uno via SoftwareSerial to make a post request to an API of temperatures values captured by the module DHT22.
I'm having problems with sending data over the TCP connection and I think it comes from the way the data is constructed (variable postRequest).

```
void httppost(){
  String postRequest = String("POST " + uri + " HTTP/1.1\r\n" +
      "Host: " + server + ":" + port + "\r\n" + 
      "Accept: *" + "/" + "*\r\n" + 
      "Content-Length: " + data.length() + "\r\n" + 
      "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n" + 
      "\r\n" + data + "\r\n");
  Serial.println(postRequest);
  delay(3000);
  Serial.flush();
  String tcpStart = "AT+CIPSTART=\"TCP\",\"" + server + "\",\"" + port + "\"";
  String sendCmd = "AT+CIPSEND=" + String(postRequest.length());
  esp.println(tcpStart); //start TCP connection
  delay(3000);
  if(esp.find("OK")){
    Serial.println("TCP connection OK");
    esp.println(sendCmd); //send the data over TCP connection
    delay(3000);
    if(esp.find(">")){
      Serial.println("Sending data");
      esp.println(postRequest);
      delay(3000);
      if(esp.find("SEND OK")){
        Serial.println("Packet sent");
        while(esp.available()){ //number of bytes/char available for reading
          char tmpResp = esp.read(); //read one char at the time
          Serial.print(tmpResp);
          if (tmpResp == '\0') continue; //terminate the while when end of the data
        }
        esp.println("AT+CIPCLOSE"); //close TCP connection
      }else{
        Serial.println("--> An error occured while sending packet");
      }
    }else{
        Serial.println("--> ESP8266 is not listening for incoming data");
    }
  }else{
    Serial.println("--> Cannot initiate TCP connection");
  }
}
  Serial.flush();
```

I'm always getting as output: "--> ESP8266 is not listening for incoming data".
Another thing that makes me think the problem is from postRequest variable it's because when I try to print the variable to Serial.monitor some lines are missing from the string.
I already try to solve this problem adding Serial.flush(), delays but none of this is the solution.

Comment: If you are only getting the **--> Cannot initiate TCP connection** then obviously `(esp.find("OK"))` is false.... you should check why and then proceed. and may be try to add more info in your post... most of us dont have esp8266 to actually run that code for debugging.

Comment: @RC0993 Thank you for your quick reply! It's not that (esp.find("OK")) is false, it's because (esp.find(">")) is false. If you see the command before, esp.println(sendCmd), sends a string.length() but from what I see the string is empty and I think the problem comes from there

Comment: don't put port in "" in CIPSTART. and you have one \r\n pair after header too much.you must wait for OK after CIPSTART before sending CIPSEND. then wait for OK after CIPSEND

Comment: I remove "\r\n" from the header and it still doesnt work.
CIPSTART works, I can find the OK after the execution. The real problem is in CIPSEND or postRequest

Comment: @Juraj any idea?

Comment: read again my comment

Comment: Hey @Raphael Is it solved?

Comment: @RC0993 nope... :( Do you have a solution for this or other?